# regex parsing a dynamic parameter from url string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a URL as follows: www.mysite.com?paramNamePrefixXXX=value

What is the best way to parse the url for the parameter name / value where XXX is dynamic/unknown..

Since I don't know the parameter name at render time.. I'd like to match on the 'startswith.. 'paramNamePrefix' + XXX (where XXX is some string..) and return the value

jquery offer a simple way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript - use that as a base, then do string matching on the results.

Comment: Is XXX 3 characters? 3 Numbers? Will there be other parameters passed?

Comment: XXX really could be anything.. So any combination of characters or numbers following 'key'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var url = "http://www.mysite.com?foo=bar&paramNamePrefixXXX=value&fizz=buzz",
    prefix = "paramNamePrefix";

var desiredValue = url.match(new RegExp('[?&]' + prefix + '.*?=(.*?)[&#$]', ''));
desiredValue = desiredValue && desiredValue[1];

console.log(desiredValue); // -> "value"
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UkHRp/3/)

Answer (score 0):

This will parse it I believe.  The only issue you would run into with the way it's written is if there was an `=` sign in your parameter value somehow.

`((?<=&|\?).+?)(?<=\=)(.+?(?=&|$))`

basically I've got it in 2 reference groups

`((?<=&|\?).+?)` <-- captures parameter name using a look behind

`(?<=\=)`

`(.+?(?=&|$))` <-- captures parameter value using a look ahead

Comment: thanks Doug.. I updated my question to be more specific.. The paramater name is what will change.. It will also contains some prefix.. so 'paramNamePrefix' + someString.. I'd like to create something that can fetch 'paramNamePrefix + someString' and it's value.. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Yes, that is what this regex will capture.  This is even going to work if the paramNamePrefix changes.